# The sequence of larger least prime divisors of Smarandache numbers Sm(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let Sm(n)=$1234567891011...$n.Numbers from concatenating the first n natural numbers ($123456789...$n)is also called a **Smarandache number**. And now consider this sequence: **numbers n greater than one, such that Sm(n) create a new record for larger least prime divisor for all $1<m<=n$**. The sequence begins, n=$2$,$3$,$7$,$61$,$121$,$133$...,with the corresponding least prime divisors of $2$,$3$,$127$,$10386763$,$278240783$,$8223519074965787731$. What is the next term after $133$ ?. I've checked Fleuren(?)'s factorizations of Smarandache numbers Sm(n), and other sites but I couldn't find the next term after $133$. I couldn't find the next term myself because of factoring problem,but I'm quite sure that the next term is greater than $319$. Can you find the next term(s) after $133$ ?

Comment: [Link](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Comment: @Lucian, that site has a limit for the number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

The next term is $133$ with the least prime divisor of $8 223 519 074 965 787 731$. And the next term after $133$ is greater than 319

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/526124)

Comment: @AlexM.I didn't intentionally do that, I really just got that answer 133,and the next term after 133 will have least prime factor with 19 digits or (much) more (!)

Comment: @AlexM.What do you mean with compete answers ?,this question is clearly very hard to answer. We are lucky if we can find the next 2 or 3 terms after 121

Comment: This was not written by me myself, it is text automatically generated by the software of MSE.

Comment: How I can delete my own answer ?. I don't know how.Can someone delete this ?

Comment: Right below your answer there is a "delete" button. Also, I suggest editing your question in order to add the new information that you have found (press the "edit" button below it).

Comment: @AlexM.Where ? I can't see it

Comment: offensive things  ? : (

Comment: Nothing offensive, don't worry. The "delete" word is on the line with "share cite edit delete flag".